# How to increase axis label text size in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hope this makes sense and thank you for your time in advance :)

I have made a bar chart to visualise the Gene Ontology enrichment of genes significantly downregulated in a microarray data set.

I am trying to increase the size of the title, "Fold enrichment", the numbers on the y axis and the labels on the x axis. I have managed to increase the size of the numbers labelling the bars (under geom_text), but I have been really struggling how to increase the size of the above text.

**My txt file contents**

process fold_enrichment     FDR

Mammillary_axonal_complex_development   200 <0.01

Corticospinal_tract_morphogenesis   200 <0.1

Notochord_morphogenesis 200 <0.1

Somitogenesis   52.27   <0.01

Ossification    16.87   <0.1

Epithelial_tube_morphogenesis   12.85   <0.1

Regulation_of_cell_differentiation  4.92    <0.01

**My code**

```
dnfgfr1d <- read.table("dnfgfr1d.txt", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2) 

bc1d <- ggplot(dnfgfr1d, aes(x = reorder(process, fold_enrichment), y = fold_enrichment, fill = FDR)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Genes down regulated by dnFGFR1") +
  geom_text(aes(label = fold_enrichment), nudge_y = 8, color = "black", size=4) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,220,by = 20), limits=c(0,220), expand=c(0,0)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Fold enrichment") +
  labs(fill='FDR') +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Regulation of cell differentiation",
                            "Epithelial tube morphogenesis",
                            "Ossification",
                            "Somitogenesis",
                            "Notochord morphogenesis",
                            "Corticospinal tract morphogenesis",
                            "Mammillary axonal complex development")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))

bc1d + scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("<0.01", "<0.1"), 
                         values=c("#3399CC", "#000099"))
```

[image]

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated as I have struggled with this for a while and I need to use this code repeatedly to generate multiple figures for my thesis.

Thanks,

Liv

Comment: This should help (read the examples toward the end of the doc): https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

Comment: Thank you jared_mamrot. The link is really useful for this code and future ones too :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a really nice overview from Henry Wang that displays all different elements that can be modified via the `theme()` function in a ggplot.

In your case you would have to use `bc1d + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14))`

Note that you can specifically adjust the size of either x- or y-axis as they are inherited from `axis.text` and therefore also work with `element.text()`

If you want more detailed information you can always visit the [reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) as @jared_mamrot commented.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That is a really useful site which I'll use in the future too

Comment: No worries, if you think this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the greyed out mark next to the answer. This helps others to see, that this was a useful answer. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

It can all be done within the theme argument.

```
bc1d + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Robbie Still, for your help!!